# Update a null value cell with an ID and the table is related to 3 others

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table that is joined from other tables. I want to update a null value in this Table by a specific number series. Below is the illustration:

The code for the Table which is called List_Codes

```
SELECT mlk.MLK_CODE
 FROM zpt
 LEFT OUTER JOIN mes ON mes.ZPT_ID = zpt.ZPT_ID 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN zmlk ON zpt.ZPT_ID = zmlk.ZPT_ID 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN mlk ON zmlk.MLK_ID = mlk.MLK_ID
 WHERE zpt.zpt_id IS NOT NULL 
 and zpt.zpt_meteringcode = '123456'
 ORDER BY mes.MES_STATUS DESC
```

Now I want to update this specific row's mlk.MLK_CODE from null to '789'. I have located this row based on the zpt.zpt_meteringcode. Any suggestions plz?
The tables look like this, and the List_Code Table is the result of the above code

```
Mlk Table
  Mlk_id Mlk_code
    1   123
    2   456

Zpt Table
Zpt_id  Zpt_meteringcode
10       123456
20       987654
30       654321
40       147852
Zmlk Table
Zpt_id  Mlk_id
20        1
30        2

List_Code Table
Zpt_id  Zpt_meteringcode    Mlk_id  Mlk_code
10       123456     
20       987654                1    123
30       654321                2    456
40       147852
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? The answer will not be the same...

Comment: I am using Oracle

Comment: Are you sure that the value of MLK_CODE is `NULL` or is it possible that there are no rows for `zmlk.MLK_ID = mlk.MLK_ID` ?

Comment: yes, I am sure. for this zpt.zpt_meteringcode = '123456' the MLK_CODE is NULL, but for others it is not. They have a value. What I want to do is to fill the Null cell with a value using an update or insert functions or if there is another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two inserts and one update statements like this.

```
INSERT INTO mlk (mlk_code)
    VALUES ( '789' ); -- Primary key is generated
```

.....

```
INSERT INTO zmlk  (zpt_id,
                     mlk_id)
        SELECT (SELECT zpt_id
                FROM   zpt
                WHERE  zpt_meteringcode = '123456'),
               (SELECT mlk_id
                FROM   mlk
                WHERE  mlk_code = '789')
        FROM   dual;
```

....

```
UPDATE list_code
    SET    ( mlk_id, mlk_code ) = (SELECT mlk_id,
                                          mlk_code
                                   FROM   mlk
                                   WHERE  mlk_code = '789')
    WHERE  zpt_meteringcode = '123456';
```